# Trying to build icecc icemon, cmake can't find Qt5

Tags: centos, qt, cmake

I'm running Centos 7 and I want Icemon for icecc. If there is a package I can install, great, but I don't know of one, so I'm attempting to build it from scratch and that relies on cmake.

My missing packages include:

- Qt5Core
- Qt5Gui
- Qt5Widgets
- Qt5
- Icecream

And optionally:

- Docbook2X

I've installed Qt5 Base and Qt5 GUI through yum, so I'm perplexed how that hasn't satisfied the requirements. I've built and installed Icecream (and configured it as a service) so I don't know why it can't find the requisite library and header files. Icecream also depends on Docbook2X for it's man pages (meaning I don't have them installed, either), and because it doesn't exist as an available package, I've only just downloaded the source for that; haven't tried building it yet.

I am not an IT guy or a DevOp (yet), I'm just a dev trying to cut my teeth on Linux beyond vim and gcc (the only two things I've ever known on this platform).

Are there Centos 7 friendly packages for these things?

Or how do I resolve this misconfiguration?

This is the output:

```
[mred@matt icemon]$ cmake .
-- Could NOT find Docbook2X (missing:  DOCBOOK_TO_MAN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- 
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * Git
 * Doxygen , Doxygen documentation generator
   Needed for generating API documentation (make doc)

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * Qt5Core
 * Qt5Gui (required version >= 5.6.0)
 * Qt5Widgets
 * Qt5 (required version >= 5.2.0)
 * Icecream , Package providing API for accessing icecc information. Provides 'icecc/comm.h' header , <http://en.opensuse.org/Icecream>

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * Docbook2X , docbook2X converts DocBook documents into the traditional Unix man page format , <http://docbook2x.sourceforge.net/>
   Required for man-page generation

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mred/d2/icemon
[mred@matt icemon]$ yum list installed | grep qt5
qt5-qtbase.x86_64                      5.6.0-7.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtbase-common.noarch               5.6.0-7.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtbase-devel.x86_64                5.6.0-7.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtbase-gui.x86_64                  5.6.0-7.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtconfiguration.x86_64             0.3.0-2.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtconfiguration-devel.x86_64       0.3.0-2.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtdeclarative.x86_64               5.6.0-3.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtx11extras.x86_64                 5.6.0-3.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtx11extras-devel.x86_64           5.6.0-3.el7                     @epel    
qt5-qtxmlpatterns.x86_64               5.6.0-4.el7                     @epel    
qt5-rpm-macros.noarch                  5.6.0-7.el7                     @epel
```

Comment: Please post the error you're seeing in the question.